# How can I check if the first 15 relevant digits in double values are the same in Boost Test framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I tried to use what seems to be designed for the job: `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE`, so I have the following test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( MultivariateNormalDensityTest )
{
  double TOLLERANCE=1e-14;  

  Eigen::Vector3d mu(0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
  Eigen::Matrix3d sigma;
  sigma << 2.0, 1.0, 0.5,
           1.0, 2.3, 0.7,
       0.5, 0.7, 1.7;

  MultivariateNormalDensity<3> mnd(mu, sigma);

  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(0.027671392189542814988, mnd(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)), TOLLERANCE);
  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(0.0027063822550173750707, mnd(Eigen::Vector3d(2.0, 1.0, 0.5)), TOLLERANCE);
  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(0.024708597088231143424, mnd(Eigen::Vector3d(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)), TOLLERANCE);
  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(0.026554587643995836849, mnd(Eigen::Vector3d(-0.3, 0.6, 1.8)), TOLLERANCE);
  //examples calculated using R
}
```

However, the first check fails with the error:

```
/home/ga1009/PhD/cpp/grzesLib/test/multivariatenormaltests.cpp(36): error in "MultivariateNormalDensityTest": difference{3.76141e-14%} between 0.027671392189542814988{0.027671392189542815} and mnd(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)){0.027671392189542805} exceeds 1e-14%
```

When I do the math I get:

```
(0.027671392189542815-0.027671392189542805)/0.027671392189542805=0.00000000000000036138406
```

which is less than 1e-14. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd don't know the library but I'd guess the tolerance is relative to the input value i.e. it's really checking that you're within 0.027*1e-14 = 2.7e-16. (And there's only one 'l' in 'tolerance'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tolerance is specified as a *percentage*, you're off by 100.  Fix:

```
double TOLERANCE=1e-12;   // Percent
```

Comment: Wow, I would never actually think that a developer would put in a real percentage! Thanks.